# Execution failed for task ':sqflite:createFullJarDebug'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart, sqflite

working on a flutter app, I ran into an issue with `sqflite` after upgrading flutter. (had the same issue with `path_provider` but replaced it with `path`.)
I tried `flutter clean` too.

**the error:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sqflite:createFullJarDebug'.
> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\fayem\AndroidStudioProjects\myapp\build\sqflite\intermediates\library_java_res\debug\res.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: myapp
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^4.1.3
  adobe_xd: ^1.0.0+1
  path: ^1.6.2
  sqflite: ^1.3.1+1
  flutter_blue: ^0.7.2

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/headphones.png
    - assets/images/flex-biceps-full.png
    - assets/images/flex-biceps.png
    - assets/images/exercises/row-1-col-1.jpg
    - assets/images/exercises/row-1-col-2.jpg
    - assets/images/exercises/row-1-col-3.jpg
    - assets/images/exercises/row-2-col-1.jpg
    - assets/images/exercises/row-2-col-2.jpg
    - assets/images/exercises/row-2-col-3.jpg
    - assets/images/exercises/row-3-col-1.jpg
    - assets/images/exercises/row-3-col-2.jpg
    - assets/images/exercises/row-3-col-3.jpg
    
  fonts:
    - family: Segoe UI
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/segoeui.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/segoeuib.ttf
          weight: 700
```

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**flutter doctor -v**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1139], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.2 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 84f3d28555 (4 days ago), 2020-10-15 16:26:19 -0700
    • Engine revision b8752bbfff
    • Dart version 2.10.2


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\fayem\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\fayem\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.50.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.15.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G920F (mobile) • 041604dc9ba00302 • android-arm64 • Android 7.0 (API 24)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

First, run flutter clean, then if it does not work delete this cache directory:

```
C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME \ .gradle\caches
```

Comment: didn't work. I got other errors, like: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.